# .net Regex, striping a matching sequence out

Tags: c#, .net, regex

My Regex knowledge is failing me and I need some help.

I'm trying to take a string input that could look as follows

```
@"RRR:domsd\ddf:sdf:dsf:f"
```

or

```
@"sds4:kwertss\wegggds:rowdf"
```

and in both case strip everything from start till after the `\` but before the first `:` that came after the firt `\` .

So results would be:

```
RRR:domsd\ddf
sds4:kwertss\wegggds
```

if should state match failed if there wasn't a `: \ :` sequence found.

I've tried the following two regs so far

1st: `@".*[:].*[\\].*[:]"` which matches everything up to the last `:` and not the first after the `\`

2nd: `@"(.+?:.+?):(.+)"` which just matches the whole string

Comment: `@"^(.*\\[^:]*)"`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems you need to use [**negated character classes**](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated):

```
^[^:]*:[^\\]*\\[^:]*(?=:)
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5e%5b%5e%3a%5cn%5d*%3a%5b%5e%5c%5c%5cn%5d*%5c%5c%5b%5e%3a%5cn%5d*%28%3f%3d%3a%29&i=RRR%3adomsd%5cddf%3asdf%3adsf%3af%0d%0asds4%3akwertss%5cwegggds%3arowdf&o=m)

**Details**:

- `^` - start of string
- `[^:]*` - 0+ chars other than `:`
- `:` - a colon
- `[^\\]*` - 0+ chars other than `\`
- `\\` - a literal `\`
- `[^:]*` - 0+ chars other than `:`
- `(?=:)` - a positive lookahead requiring a `:`.

In C#:

```
var m = Regex.Match(s, @"^[^:]*:[^\\]*\\[^:]*(?=:)");
var res = string.Empty;
if (m.Success) 
{
     res = m.Value;
}
```

Comment: Your answer is correct, but it won't fail if there wasn't a `: \ :` sequence found. you are missing a `:` at the end. `^(.*:.*[\\][^:]*):`

Comment: Yes, let's add `(?=:)`

Answer (score 0):

you can use the regex (with global and multiline flags)

```
(^.*\\.*?):
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/sDWIHj/1)

Answer (score 0):

You could use the regex: `^(.*:.*[\\][^:]*):`.
This will fail if there wasn't a `: \ :` sequence found.
The match would be the part between brackets.

[Here](https://regex101.com/r/UIg0zk/1) you can see a demo.